# Moodle non-code question was closed although much of the same Q/A was not closed. How can I change it to get it reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

This question was closed: ["Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: Cannot override a standard property value." thrown in Moodle [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76987339/coding-error-detected-it-must-be-fixed-by-a-programmer-cannot-override-a-stan)

> This question is not about programming or software development. It is not currently accepting answers.

I understand that this is a black box question: there isn't any code that might be traced back. And therefore it should be off-topic.

More on this:

> This question does not appear to be about a specific programming
> problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by
> programmers. You can edit the question so it's on-topic or see if it
> can be answered on another Stack Exchange site, but be sure to read
> the on-topic page for a site before posting there.

But still, Moodle itself is kind of a software tool that can be changed in the backend and managed in the frontend, it is a tool for many educational institutions from universities till schools, and it also has a tag here on Stack Overflow and seems to have quite a few other questions that do not show any code either but are not closed, like [Moodle - Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: The data source class does not exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334967/11154841)

How can I get this question reopened, if not by showing the source code behind the bug? I might be able to get the code from the server or from the repository, but I admit that I am too new to the whole platform to even start with code search, so that I try a lucky fix at first.

PS: I also flagged it to be moved to *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)*, but I asked the moderator to check this as well. And the flag has now been pending for quite some time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I squint I feel like the question that's closed is one in a different context to the other one. Yes, the problems are similar, but your question has the texture of asking for support, whereas the other one...kinda *doesn't*.

It's weird.  I think both are asking about support, to be honest.  But the texture and knee-jerk response I have about your question isn't quite equivalent to the other question, since it's not as apparent.

Maybe the real sentiment here is about scope.

If you intend to get support for Moodle, then this probably isn't the right place for that question.

If you have a specific programming error regarding Moodle, you should include your source code and enough info to make it so that we get what's going on.

Comment: That is the point, I am writing more from the viewpoint of an end user of Moodle. Getting the source code and testing would take quite some time. The debug mode of the tool shows the same error message. If it is not a programming question, and yes, it is not, I wonder why no moderator just moves it to Web Apps SE where it would belong then. And perhaps, it is since the other question is on-topic? To any moderator who can move it, it is better to move it than to leave it closed on Stack Overflow as it is now. But best would be to reopen it after some changes, but without the code behind it.

Comment: @questionto42:  Web Apps's own Help page [provides info on what is and is not on-topic there](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help), and this suggests [your question is not on-topic](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/894/what-kind-of-questions-can-i-ask-here-the-detailed-version).  Don't presume that just because a site is named in one way that your question could fit there.

Comment: Then it is unclear where it could be asked at all, it does not seem to fit to to any SE.

Comment: @questionto42: I think you're getting it.  This kind of question probably wouldn't work on the Stack Exchange network.  Might be worth reaching out to Moodle though.

Comment: The question was - rightfully - deleted and I guess I will have to look up the source code to bring it to life again. Let us see when I take the time for that...

Answer (score 4):

> But still, Moodle itself is kind of a software tool that can be changed in the backend and managed in the frontend, it is a tool for many educational institutions from universities till schools, and it also has a tag here on Stack Overflow and seems to have quite a few other questions that do not show any code either but are not closed, like Moodle - Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: The data source class does not exist.

The other question is about trying to upgrade an installation of Moodle, a tool that is commonly used by programmers. That's on topic. OP apparently intends to use the program, once properly upgraded, to manage self-authored code.

The question you're advocating for, appears to be about trying to *use someone else's* webapp that happens to use Moodle, because something goes wrong that appears to be in the Moodle part of the system. That's not on topic. There is no evidence that OP actually wrote any code in order to get into this situation.

If the webapp is in fact OP's own, then the question needs to be completely recast to make this clear, and to show a proper MRE of a **complete system** that can reproduce the problem (while still otherwise being **minimal**).

Comment: That said, this tag doesn't seem generally very good. A quick check suggests that +2 is a 90th percentile score for questions thus tagged (vs., say, +4 for Python).

Comment: "manage self-authored code" I doubt that this is true. Users of Moodle usually do not code themselves, it is a platform that they just take over. The Moodle tool is just the same over there as it is in my Q, just without the same data. I think one could say that both Q are about the same Moodle webapp and not about the code behind it. And it seems that the error in question is linked to any user that existed before the upgrade, but not to new users, which hints at an upgrade problem as well. Perhaps I oversaw or misunderstood something in your answer now.

Comment: That was my interpretation based on the questions and on the fact that the tag has been able to attract around 3000 questions without anyone calling for its burnination. Maybe we've overlooked something?

Comment: Moodle is an LMS (Learning Management System), I won't say it is a tool commonly used by programmers. IMO the question doesn't really look like a programming question and is rather more in a "Web Administration" context (sounds like a bad cache somewhere).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat besides that, this is also a case of ignoring the "and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" bit. Just because something might be a tool commonly used by programmers does not make all questions about it on-topic. At least, that is what the written rules seem to imply, but it is written as if intended to create two camps. And it must be said that this creates a tiring amount of meta posts about why tool questions are closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Gimby I'm inclined to agree, and that has a lot to do with why I think the site made a mistake in accepting such questions in the first place. On the other hand, an alternate model that's considerably broader in scope (as Codidact has assumed) also seems to be workable - at least, at low volumes. At any rate, it feels like we're overdue to revisit the topic on Meta.

Comment: Not sure whether the Moodle tag needs a clean up just after this discussion. This was just a weird try to find a quick fix for a low prio issue at the Moodle Tracker (github).